# Using Regex to extract part of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a series of strings and I need to extract a certain portion of them. I would like to use regular expressions to do this. This strings all have this general form:

```
content/landdata/files/Albuquerque_123.zip
```

Most of the string is static except for the city name. It could be any city name.

I've gotten as far as this:

```
(?!content/landdata/files/)(?:[A-Za-z_-])*[_][0-9]{1,}(?!\\.zip)
```

Which will give me `Albuquerque_123` but I'm having trouble getting rid of the `_123`.

Comment: Is it always `_123` at the end, or is it just some integer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match.Groups%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) property.

For example:

```
    var testString = "content/landdata/files/Albuquerque_123.zip";
    var regex = new Regex(@"content/landdata/files/([A-Za-z_-]+)_[0-9]+\.zip");
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(testString).Groups[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`?:` means *non-capturing group* so get rid of it in the group you actually want to capture.

```
(?!content/landdata/files/)(?:[A-Za-z_-])*[_][0-9]{1,}(?!\\.zip)
```

should be

```
(?!content/landdata/files/)([A-Za-z_-]*)_[0-9]+(?!\\.zip)
```

... and then you can just query the `Groups` property of the match.

[Tested here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a bit more context in regards to "getting rid of the _123?"

My understanding of what you are asking for is as follows: You are essentially just trying to remove the _123 from the regex'd string so it becomes /content/landdata/files/[City Name]

So if this is the case, perform a substitution on the _123.

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern =  "_123";
      string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");

      Console.WriteLine("Output: " + result);                             
  }
}
```

I didn't really test the above code, and there may be issues with it. There is probably also a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm nearly sure that _123 part is not static like that.

Comment: Probably not, but as I said, I was just looking for more context.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - puts the city in the capturing group (removed the ?: and move the * inside the group from yours)

```
content\/landdata\/files\/([A-Za-z_-]*)[_][0-9]{1,}(?!\\.zip)
```

Comment: `[_]` could be simply `_`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are almost there. Consider the following regex...

```
(?!content/landdata/files/)(?:[A-Za-z_-])+(?=[_][0-9]{1,}\.zip)
```

Good Luck!